# What are the few practical use cases of Haskell's init function?

Tags: haskell

Haskell's init function takes a list and returns everything except its last element.  In what situation is such a functionality useful? I am looking for one or two practical use cases.

e.g.

```
> init [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Well, in a situation where you need to drop the last element. What do you want us to tell you? It's just a function that does exactly that. Try to implement it yourself using head & tail and you'll see that it's quite convenient to have a function already available.

Comment: I remember using it when doing some Web scraping, if you are looking for some real world use case.

Comment: Could you tell me in what situation you have found yourself needing to drop the last element?

Comment: @Sibi Why do you need to drop the last element in your web scraping task?

Comment: @Boon Because I didn't need the last element tag present in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often times in functional reactive stream programming the first and/or last elements are dummies to indicate start and end. Haskell has laziness so lists can be used as streams.

Comment: Thanks - that's a good use case.